# CSS: Submit button width:auto not wide enough in Safari

Tags: html, css

I am having the most frustrating problem. I am trying to put a text input field and a submit button joined together on the same line.

Everything looks great when I view it in Firefox, but on Safari, the width of the submit button is not as wide as it should be.

Notice the "JOIN NOW" button in this image:

[image: Button Example]

Could anyone help me out in figuring out what's going wrong here?

Here's a link to the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bf2qaycr/

```css
.form-button-append {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.form-button-append input {
  border-right: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.form-button-append button {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
button, input {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d4d4d4;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: visible;
}
button {
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-button-append">
  <input id="EmailJoin" placeholder="Email Address" type="email">
  <button type="submit">JOIN NOW</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Odd, it worked fine for me in Safari.

Comment: there are multiple declarations of width in your css for 'button' - `width: 100%;` and `width: auto;`

Comment: @LukeSheltraw That's strange, I try either the embedded code or the JSFiddle link, and the right side of the button is cut off.

Comment: I viewed it on a 2015 Macbook, Version 10.1, using your jsfiddle link.

Comment: @LukeSheltraw It also has this problem for me on Safari for iOS (iPhone and iPad)

Comment: That's very odd